# How Inject a directive to an Component with ViewChild in Angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, material-design

I'm using Full-Calendar and I want to Inject mat-button directive to buttons inside component to style them with Material Design.

is there any way i could do it with ViewChild ? or any other solution. Thanks

Comment: you want to have buttons inside of fullcalender Material Design right?

Comment: @Plochie yeah,  kinda. I want them to be like other buttons in my application,  that's why I have to inject the directive to make it work.

Comment: Actually unless and until you change the code of fullcalender you can not do that.